# Chromedriver does not always switch in the window

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use this method:

```
for (String handle: driver.getWindowHandles ()) {driver.switchTo (). window (handle);}
```

but Chrome not always switch. I also wait for the value of window title:

```
waitDriver.until (ExpectedConditions.titleIs ("new title"));
```

But, (if I understand right), Webdriver not switched in the new window. It remains in the old window and waits for the header in the same window rather than in the new one. So I can't wait title and window I need. Any exception or correct switch.
The result is:

```
Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for title to be "new titile". Current title: "old titile".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try running in Debug mode? It may tell you what the problem is.

Or alternatively try following logic (creating an `ArrayList<String>` for window handles and then removing the old handle from list.) If that works for you, use this as a util method and call where ever needed.
:

```
String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
    try{
        List<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        newTab.remove(oldTab);
        driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Reporter.log("No new tab found!! " + "Number of tabs currently open = "+driver.getWindowHandles().size(), Base.DEBUG_MODE);
        throw e; // or do whatever you wanna do here
    }
```

If you wanna create a static method for switching to a new window and put this to your utils, here is one approach:

```
public static void switchToNewTab(WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
    String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
    try{
        List<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        newTab.remove(oldTab);
        driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Reporter.log("No new tab found!! " + "Number of tabs currently open = "+driver.getWindowHandles().size(), Base.DEBUG_MODE);
        throw e;
    }   
}
```